# how to return an array inside an array javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, for-loop

i have an array inside an array...how do i return all the values using a for loop in javascript/angular?

for example my json...

```
[
    {
        "Name": "element1",
        "Attributes": [
           {"file":"document.doc"},
           {"file":"document2.doc"}
        ]
    },

    {
        "Name": "element2",
        "Attributes": [
           {"file":"document3.doc"},
           {"file":"document4.doc"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "element3",
        "Attributes": [
           {"file":"document5.doc"},
           {"file":"document6.doc"}
        ]
    }
]
```

having a tough time just returning all the files within attributes...only seem to be getting the first one everytime.

EDIT:

what i have so far..

```
function getAllFiles() {
            for (var i = 0; i < Attributes.file.length; i++) {
              return Attributes.file[i];
            }
          }
```

Comment: Please post 1) What the expected output should be, and 2) what you have tried so far.

Comment: *"...only seem to be getting the first one everytime."* Show us the code where that's happening, and we can point out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the methods how to get the desired output, using `Array#reduce`.

```js
var json = [{Name:"element1",Attributes:[{file:"document.doc"},{file:"document2.doc"}]},{Name:"element2",Attributes:[{file:"document3.doc"},{file:"document4.doc"}]},{Name:"element3",Attributes:[{file:"document5.doc"},{file:"document6.doc"}]}],
    res = json.reduce(function(s,a){
        s.push(...a.Attributes.map(c => c.file));
        return s;
      }, []);
    console.log(res);
```

**ES5**

```js
var json = [{Name:"element1",Attributes:[{file:"document.doc"},{file:"document2.doc"}]},{Name:"element2",Attributes:[{file:"document3.doc"},{file:"document4.doc"}]},{Name:"element3",Attributes:[{file:"document5.doc"},{file:"document6.doc"}]}],
    res = json.reduce(function(s,a){
        s = s.concat(a.Attributes.map(c => c.file));
        return s;
      }, []);
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: this works...but i'm using underscore.js to make it work with angularjs...so ill update when i got it working

Comment: @jeremy How is it? Works?

Answer (score 1):

```
try    

var files = [];
json.forEach(function(obj) {
obj.Attributes.forEach(function (f) {
files.push(f.file); })
});
```

this loops on the json array then on each element's attributes then adds the vilue of `file`

Comment: hmm this is just returning an empty array but getting the correct number of empty arrays

Comment: this is based on the exact json structure above althought i;m wondering how `getAllFiles()` can access `Attributes.file` ... and `Attributes` is an array in the above structure ..

Answer (score 0):

You could show all the files using Array methods like `map` and `reduce`:

```js
var data = [{
        "Name": "element1",
        "Attributes": [{
                "file": "document.doc"
            },
            {
                "file": "document2.doc"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "Name": "element2",
        "Attributes": [{
                "file": "document3.doc"
            },
            {
                "file": "document4.doc"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "element3",
        "Attributes": [{
                "file": "document5.doc"
            },
            {
                "file": "document6.doc"
            }
        ]
    }
];

var files = data.map(function (obj) {
    return obj.Attributes.map(function (i) {
        return i.file;
    });
}).reduce(function (x, y) {
    return x.concat(y);
});

console.log(files);
```

Although [Kind user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6695924/kind-user)'s answer is better:

```
var data = [{
        "Name": "element1",
        "Attributes": [{
                "file": "document.doc"
            },
            {
                "file": "document2.doc"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "Name": "element2",
        "Attributes": [{
                "file": "document3.doc"
            },
            {
                "file": "document4.doc"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "element3",
        "Attributes": [{
                "file": "document5.doc"
            },
            {
                "file": "document6.doc"
            }
        ]
    }
];

var files = data.reduce(function(acc, val) {
    return acc.concat(
        val.Attributes.map(function(attribute) {
            return attribute.file;
        })
    );
}, []);

console.log(files);
```

I renamed some variables so that the code makes more sense (to me).

Answer (score -1):

Something like outerArray.innerArray. in your case arrayName.Attributes should work.